# .style.display="none" doesn't work with click function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, display

When I click the start button the content with `winning-message` class must be hidden. But when I click it doesn't happen. Can you help me?
Here is the whole of my code: https://codepen.io/citakilkay/pen/OJRZway

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-start").click(function() {
    $(".winning-message").style.display = "none";
  });
});
```

```css
.winning-message {
  display: grid;
  position: absolute;
  width: $width-board;
  height: $height-board;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.336);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-start col-4 my-5">Start</button>
<div class="winning-message" id="winningMessage">
  <div data-winning-message-text>
    <h1>Player 1 Won!</h1>
  </div>
  <button onclick="startGame()" class="btn btn-outline-secondary restartButton">RESTART</button>
</div>
```

I figured out it. Thank you for your response. But the problem was type="submit".Because when I click hide(); function, It disappears and appears. So It must have been type="button".Please somebody type this as an answer and I will accept it for true answer.

Comment: You didn't include jQuery.

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't exactly in depth debugging!

Comment: `$(".winning-message")` is a jQuery object, which is also a collection of matching DOM elements. So you could probably do this: `$(".winning-message")[0].style.display="none";` to select the first item and hide it. But `.hide()` is best

Comment: Do any of the answers work for you?

Comment: I figured out it. Thank you for your response. But the problem was type="submit".Because when I click hide(); function, It disappears and appears. So It must have been type="button".Please somebody type this as an answer and I will accept it for true answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing jQuery and Javascript APIs, but you can fix this with each

```
$(".btn-start").click(function(){
    $(".winning-message").each(function() {
      this.style.display="none";
    });
});
```

The other way you can do it is with jQuery's .css function

```
    $(".winning-message").css("display","none");
```

Comment: I tried both of them but they didn't work.

Comment: Or more preferably, `$(".winning-message").hide()`

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use [`.hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/).

```
$(".winning-message").hide();
```

Live example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-start").click(function() {
    $(".winning-message").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.winning-message {
  display: grid;
  position: absolute;
  width: $width-board;
  height: $height-board;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.336);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-start col-4 my-5">Start</button>
<div class="winning-message" id="winningMessage">
  <div data-winning-message-text>
    <h1>Player 1 Won!</h1>
  </div>
  <button onclick="startGame()" class="btn btn-outline-secondary restartButton">RESTART</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's two issues here.

The first is that you're attempting to use native JS properties on a jQuery object. This cannot work. As you've got a jQuery object instantiated, use a jQuery method to hide the element. `hide()` in this case:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $(".btn-start").click(function() {
    $(".winning-message").hide();
  });
});
```

The second issue is in your HTML. Within the Codepen your full HTML shows that the `.btn-start` element is a `<button type="submit">`. As such clicking this button will submit the parent `form` and redirect the user to the location provided in the `action` of that `form` element.

To fix this you need to either remove the `<form />` element (given that it appears to serve no purpose in your logic anyway) or call `preventDefault()` on the click event raised when `.btn-start` is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You have added an inline click reference to a function you have not defined on the `restartButton`. And you are mixing JQuery and Javascript as ControlAltDel mentions.

The example below is fully commented, the key line in your case is:   `$(".winning-message").hide();`

```js
// Run startGame function on startup
// Uncomment the line below to automatically hide the message / start the game on load
//startGame()

// Add function to start button
$(".btn-start").click(function() {

  startGame();

});

// Define startGame function
function startGame() {

  // Hide winning message
  $(".winning-message").hide();
  // The line below acts in a similar way
  //$(".winning-message").css('display', 'none');

}

// Add click event to winButton
$(".winButton").click(function() {

  // Show winning message
  $(".winning-message").show();
  // The line below acts in a similar way
  //$(".winning-message").css('display', 'inherit')

});
```

```css
.winning-message {
  display: grid;
  position: absolute;
  width: $width-board;
  height: $height-board;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.336);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-start col-4 my-5">Start</button>

<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary winButton">Show winning message</button>

<div class="winning-message" id="winningMessage">
  <div data-winning-message-text>
    <h1>Player 1 Won!</h1>
  </div>
  <button onclick="startGame()" class="btn btn-outline-secondary restartButton">RESTART</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use JQuery **hide** function to do it:

```js
$(".btn-start").click(function(){
    $(".winning-message").hide();
});
```

Also you can use **fadeOut** function if you want to have an animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this js code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $(".btn-start").click(function(){
        $(".winning-message").css('display', 'none');
    });

});
```